# Saving full webpages to sdcard in android

Tags: android, android-webview

hi developers i am developing a web based application in android. i want to download a webpage to sdcard to make loading of the webpage make faster. so i download the html file using the below code

```
try {
                //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
                //this is the file to be downloaded
                URL url = new URL("http://venusdigitalarcade.com/index.html");

                //create the new connection
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                //set up some things on the connection
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                //and connect!
                urlConnection.connect();

                //set the path where we want to save the file
                //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
                //sd card.
                File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
                //which we want to save the file as.
                File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"venus.html");

                //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

                //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                //this is the total size of the file
                int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
                //variable to store total downloaded bytes
                int downloadedSize = 0;

                //create a buffer...
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

                //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
                while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                        //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                        fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                        //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                        downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                        //this is where you would do something            to               report       the prgress, like this maybe
   //                           updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);

                }
                //close the output stream when done
                fileOutput.close();

        //catch some possible errors...
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

this code only saves the html writings there is no designing part and css file and contents like images and videos

how can i download the full webpages with design and javascrpts and css?

Comment: please comment here if you dont understand my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  create  a  file list  for every resource  you need  or use a web crawler like http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/